# How to set brightness, contrast and saturation on a camera

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, video-capture

I'm capturing video through a webcam using AV Foundation and I'd like to be able to set brightness, contrast and saturation on the video being captured. I know that [it's very easy to do on Windows using DirectShow or Media Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I can't find anything like that in AV Foundation.

Also, the pixel format of the captured video can vary from capture to capture, so the method of setting brightness, contrast and saturation should not depend on it. i.e. if there is a way to do that only for YUY2, then I can't use it, since it has to work for all of pixel formats.